# JVM Fatal Error SIGSEGV on Java 6

Tags: java, jboss, jvm

On planned server reboots (due to patches and upgrades), we are noticing that our application server (jboss) is failing to start up or dying a couple hours later.  This only happens intermittently (maybe 10% of reboots).  The only way to fix the issue is to restart the application server.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xf6b803f1, pid=25757, tid=2408274800
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x1373f1]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /apps/appserver/JBossEnterprisePlatform-4.3.0.GA/jboss-as/bin/hs_err_pid25757.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

After doing some googling I have seen some posts saying that this is a known bug with Java 6 update 18 but I am unable to find more info on it as the java sun pages no longer exist.  Has anyone experienced this?  We are running on 64-bit Dell servers.  We don't want to upgrade to 64 bit java as that might just cause more issues.  Would doing a minor version upgrade help?

Comment: *"We don't want to upgrade to 64 bit java as that might just cause more issues."* what issues could be possibly worse than a segfaulting VM?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know if it would help or not but as this is a reproducible problem, I suggest you try updating to Java 6 update 45 which is ~2 years older.

If possible I would suggest you move off using 32-bit JVM on a server.  I am probably wrong, but my first reaction would be that this will cause more problems than it will solve (unless you have some 32-bit shared libraries).

You might also want to update to JBoss 8.2 or 9 with Java 8 (the only version with public support)